# Function Evaluation Timed Out When Adding A Property To Watch

Tags: c#, wcf

Here's some context: I have two applications (a client and a server), they communicate via WCF using a shared DLL containing the service contract, and an own service proxy. The service contract contains the property `TreeFront`.

---

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IOwnCallbackContract))]
public interface IOwnServiceContract
{

    bool TreeFront
    {
        [OperationContract]
        get;
        [OperationContract]
        set;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    void DisplayString(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    void Subscribe();

    [OperationContract]
    void Unsubscribe();
}
```

---

**Service Proxy**

```
public class OwnServiceProxy : DuplexClientBase<IOwnServiceContract>, IOwnServiceContract
{

    public OwnServiceProxy(object context) : base(context) { }

    public OwnServiceProxy(string configurationName) : base(configurationName){ }

    public bool TreeFront
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Channel.TreeFront;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Channel.TreeFront = value;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayString(string s)
    {
        base.Channel.DisplayString(s);
        bool b = TreeFront;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        base.Channel.Subscribe();
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        base.Channel.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Recently a problem has occured when I was debugging the service proxy. I added `TreeFront` to the watch and put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method `DisplayString()`. When entering the breakpoint I get the message *"Function evaluation timed out."* [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytjVL.png).
And when I refresh the value I get the message *"Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context."*. I looked everywhere for a solution but nothing worked. I tried

- disabling/enabling *property evaluation and other implicit function calls*
- enabling *use legacy c# and vb expression evaluators*

Neither of these options worked. I know I could use a temporary variable and add that to the watch, but is there a way around that? It's probably not best practice but in my case I need to be able to directly inspect the value of the property.

Comment: As a clean approach and better separation of concerns why can't you create a DataContract and use it to exchange the data?

Comment: @SivaGopal I'm sorry but I don't quite understand. What would I need a DataContract for? (I am pretty much new in this field so I don't know how that would help)